# Primefaces3.4 DateTime Support in Line Chart

Tags: jsf-2, charts, primefaces, timeline

I am trying to display a datetime line chart, in a continuous style, using primefaces 3.4 which internally uses jqplot.
It should be possible, according to this:
http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=2180
however, my result is just a normal discrete chart.
Has anyone succeeded?

The primefaces author says:
*Using new extender feature you can configure the chart the way you want before it is rendered on client side. Extender is simply a javascript function that is called before the plot is drawn so that you can override PrimeFaces provided attributes and add more to support any jqplot configuration option*

What am I supposed to put in the extender for the timeline to work?

This was promising:
kevindoran1.blogspot.co.nz/2012/02/using-google-charts-with-jsf.html
but xmlns:ti="http://tradeintel.co.nz/custom" no longer exists (?)

btw, continuous and discrete explained =
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#Discrete_vs_Continuous

Any alternative (free) chart libs, that I can easily integrate with JSF2 ?
This kevindoran1.blogspot.co.nz/2012/02/using-google-charts-with-jsf.html was promising
but  xmlns:ti="http://tradeintel.co.nz/custom" no longer exists (?)

Comment: I tried to follow this approach:
http://www.hatemalimam.com/2010/11/19/google-chart-tools-interactive-charts-aka-visualization-api-with-jsf-2/
It works, but there is very limited control over the chart, via JSF and Ajax. For Example I want to hide/show the chart via a JSF button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work with primefaces look at my detailed post here http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=23891&p=78637#p78637

If you have any doubt don't hesitate asking me the details

Comment: Thanks man!(Note for readers: put millis from epoc on Xaxis, e.g. using getTime() from a java.​util.​Date object.